# FakeFS causing open-uri open to cause "No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, open-uri

I was using rails 4.1.4 with fakefs 0.5.2.
I tried to upgrade to rails 4.2.0 and now my tests fail with this error:

```
Errno::ENOENT:
   No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - https://google.com/
```

I tried searching and finally arrived that this is caused probably by FakeFS as when I call open in a rails console, it works as expected as follows:

```
2.1.0 :001 > link = open("https://google.com")
 => #<Tempfile:/tmp/open-uri20150227-21959-18cqr0h>
2.1.0 :003 > require 'fakefs/spec_helpers'
 => true 
2.1.0 :004 > FakeFS.activate!
 => true 
2.1.0 :005 > link = open("https://google.com")
 Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - https://google.com
```

Does anyone know the cause of this?

Update:
So, what I decided to do eventually was to replace open-uri with [curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb). There are also other alternatives such as [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) and [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html).
Thanks

Comment: See also https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs/issues/290

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in `NET::SSH.sftp.download`.Use net/scp

```
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/sftp'
require 'net/scp'

 begin

    puts '------------------------'
    puts 'Connecting to server...'

    Net::SSH.start(host, username, :password => password, :port => port) do |ssh|

      puts '------------------------'
      puts 'Entered the server...'

      puts '------------------------'
      puts 'Listing directory..'

      puts ssh.sftp.dir.entries(directory.to_s).map { |e| e.name }

      puts local_filename_path = Dir.pwd+'/'+filename.to_s

      puts remote_filename_path = "directory.to_s+filename.to_s"

      puts '------------------------'
      puts "Download file #{remote_filename_path}..."

      ssh.scp.download!(remote_filename_path, local_filename_path ) do |ch, name, sent, total|
        puts "#{name}: #{sent}/#{total}"
      end
      puts '------------------------'
      puts "File download #{remote_filename_path}!!"
      puts '------------------------'


      puts "done! exit!"

      ssh.wait!
      # ssh.execute! 'exit'
      ssh.close

    end

  rescue Timeout::Error
    @error = "  Timed out"
  rescue Errno::EHOSTUNREACH
    @error = "  Host unreachable"
  rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
    @error = "  Connection refused"
  rescue Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed
    @error = "  Authentication failure"
  end

  if defined?(@error) then
    puts @error
  end
```